# viewDidAppear Delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm experiencing long delays (1-3 seconds) between the calls to viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

This happens after loading a large view, sometimes printing wait_fences as well.
No connection to UIAlertView or any of the other causes I see in related questions.

There isn't anything going on in viewWillAppear, calling super and not performing any animations.

What could be the reason for this long delay?

Comment: Are you doing some kind of animation in viewWillAppear?

Comment: No. The only viewWillAppear implementation in the app, just uses NSLog to print a simple log.

Comment: are you calling [super viewWillAppear] and [super viewDidAppear] properly?

Comment: Yes, throughout the app.

Comment: can you add some part of code- of viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear here...seems like a strange problem...

Comment: When you say "This happens after loading a large view," could it actually be the delay is coming from the will and did Disappear methods when leaving that larger view... Maybe it's a memory cleanup issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced exactly the same thing.
I had a tableview with an image in each cell.
I preload the images into an array but was still having this weird delay between these calls.
Making the images smaller (from full camera size to 36X36) when put into the array did the trick.

I think the delay is just the UI loading all the elements. 
Make your elements more efficient.